# Finiteness  properties of general topological spaces 

Tags: gt.geometric-topology

It  is  known  that all  metric compact  ANR  have  the  homotopy type  of finite CW complexes. Which  spaces  are homotopy  equivalent or  finitely  dominated  by CW  complexes of finite  type?

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ be a space, which we may as well assume connected. If $X$ is an ANR, then Milnor gives that $X$ is homotopy equivalent to a countable CW-complex $X'$. The question of when $X'$ is homotopy equivalent to a complex of finite type is addressed in Theorem A of

Wall, C. T. C.
Finiteness conditions for CW-complexes. 
Ann. of Math. (2) 81 1965 56–69.

and discussed further in

Wall, C. T. C.
Finiteness conditions for CW complexes. II. 
Proc. Roy. Soc. Ser. A 295 1966 129–139.

Note the necessary condition that $\pi_1(X')$ be finitely presented. 
I suspect there are more modern references building on Wall's work, but I couldn't find any.

Comment: Bestvina and Brady famously demonstrated the necessity of the finitely presented hypothesis. They constructed a group of type FP_2 which is not finitely presented.

Comment: (Or have I got this mixed up with the D(2) problem, which is still open?  Anyway, the Bestvina--Brady paper is a good modern reference.) 